# How to add an index.ascx file or index.html file in a placeholder

Tags: jquery, html, stylesheet, placeholder

How do I add an index.ascx file or an index.html file in an asp:Placeholder inside a page.ascx file? 
I already referenced the stylesheet, the jquery code, the script and the index.ascx file in the page.ascx file, how do I get it into a placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<%Html.RenderPartial();%>
```